# How send image to WhatsApp from my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, whatsapp

In July 2013 WhatsApp opened their URL schemes for our apps. I have sent text to Whatsapp from my application, but now I would like send a image. How send a image to Whatsapp?

I'm not sure how do it.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

If I understand them correctly, just make an instance of UIDocumentInteractionController, init it with your image and then it should be possible to send images via the built-in action button of the UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Thank you very much. I try it and with UIDocumentInteracionController I got send image via WhatsApp.

Answer (score 6):

Per their [documentation](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013), you need to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`. To selectively display only Whatsapp in the document controller (it is presented to the user, at which point they can select Whatsapp to share to), follow their instructions:

> Alternatively, if you want to show only WhatsApp in the application list (instead of WhatsApp plus any other public/*-conforming apps) you can specify a file of one of aforementioned types saved with the extension that is exclusive to WhatsApp:

```
images - «.wai» which is of type net.whatsapp.image
videos - «.wam» which is of type net.whatsapp.movie
audio files - «.waa» which is of type net.whatsapp.audio
```

You need to save the image to disk, and then create a `UIDocumentInteractionController` with that file URL.

Here is some example code:

```
_documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:_imageFileURL];
_documentController.delegate = self;
_documentController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
[_documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try it and with UIDocumentInteracionController I got send image via WhatsApp.

Comment: Is it possible to share an image AND a text in a single share?

Comment: According to this post, since November you can do both. Here's the post that explains how. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077338/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp-or-facebook

It is for Android development, please let me know if you want me to write it for Obj-C/Swift.

Comment: @LaurentRivard How to share both in Obj-C? I have [asked a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741858/ios-share-image-and-text-to-whatsapp)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a finally working solution for Swift. The method is triggered by a button. you can find some more explanations [here](http://tobiastheil.com/whatsapp-image-sharing-swift/)

```
import UIKit

class ShareToWhatsappViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    var documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func shareToWhatsapp(sender: UIButton) {
        let image = UIImage(named: "my_image") // replace that with your UIImage

        let filename = "myimage.wai"
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, false)[0] as! NSString
        let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/" + filename).stringByExpandingTildeInPath
        UIImagePNGRepresentation(image).writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: false)
        let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: destinationPath)! as NSURL

        documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileUrl)
        documentController.delegate = self
        documentController.UTI = "net.whatsapp.image"
        documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: false)
    }
}
```