# Share image on Whatsapp from an iOS app without using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

I have shared an image on Whatsapp from an iOS app using UIDocumentInteractionController. But, right now, I need to share an image without using UIDocumentInteractionController. Is it possible?

Comment: hey refer the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894757/ios-share-image-text-to-whatsapp/47056129#47056129

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, since all apps are sandboxed the `UIDocumentInteractionController` is the only way to share files among apps.

Read the FAQ on [integrate WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013) it only mentions `UIDocumentInteractionController` for sharing files (images, video and audio). You can if you only want WhatsApp to show up change the extension to of the file to:

- images      - .wai which is of type net.whatsapp.image
- videos      - .wam which is of type net.whatsapp.movie
- audio files - .waa which is of type net.whatsapp.audio

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would not want to use the UIDocumentInteractionController. Maybe a temporary fix like this can help:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]])
{

}
```