# Share multiple videos in whatsapp

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, whatsapp

I want to share multiple videos in whatsapp.I do it using UIActivityViewController.First I store the videos on iPhone and send URLs(NSURL).If I send a one URL it works but If I send multiple URLs it does not work.UIActivityViewController does not show whatsapp icon also.

```
NSURL *urlOne = url;
NSURL *urlTwo = url;

NSArray *items  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:urlOne,urlTwo,nil];

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypeMail,
                                UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to know,whatsapp support multiple videos sharing and if it supports how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share one video at a time. Kindly refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295817/1242673