# Share Image and text together on WhatsApp in swift

Tags: ios, whatsapp, uiactivitycontroller

I share image and text using `UIActivitycontroller` it works fine for all application installed in device but in `WhatsApp`, it only share text not image. Why?

So, what i have to do share image and text together in `WhatsApp` in iOS.

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: @LorenzOliveto Thanks for your reply. But using above link either I will only be share image or text at WhatsApp but my requirement is to share an image with text in WhatsApp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - Share image + text to WhatsApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894757/ios-share-image-text-to-whatsapp)

Answer (score 6):

You can post Image or Text on WhatsApp. However you can't post both at a time as whatsapp does not provide any API that you can add caption and post image with text.

Now there is an api available for interacting with WhatsApp:

**http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013**

Also Find below helpful answer:

You can use the UIDocumentInteractionController as mentioned in the 2nd answer to this question as of August 4, 2014: **[Share image/text through WhatsApp in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354417/share-image-text-through-whatsapp-in-an-ios-app#51684451)**

Comment: Still not able to share both image and text?

Comment: Yes, still not able. How can it be possible?;)